# Cross-fade animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am trying to make my cross-fade image animation load after it reaches a certain distance from the top of the page, 100px. I have tried adding the following JQuery, however I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate any help on this, thank you!

I've uploaded my **source** to here http://jsfiddle.net/6c8w76bx/12/

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="cf3" class="cf3FadeIn">
<img class="bottom" src="http://dvqlxo2m2q99q.cloudfront.net/000_clients/192648/file/192648142935Bv3.jpg" alt="192648142935Bv3.jpg">
  <img class="top" src="http://dvqlxo2m2q99q.cloudfront.net/000_clients/192648/file/1926481429316kf.jpg" alt="1926481429316kf.jpg">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeIn {
   0% {
     opacity:1;
   }
   25% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
   opacity:0;
 }
}

.cf3FadeIn {
  position:relative;
  height:544px;
  width:957px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.cf3FadeIn img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

.cf3FadeIn img.top {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

JQuery:

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#cf3').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+100) {
            $(this).addClass("cf3FadeIn");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't understand your code. You already have `class="cf3FadeIn"` specified for the `div` inside your HTML. Moreover, the HTML which you've mentioned in your question is completely different than that inside the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/6c8w76bx/12/).

Comment: Don't understand, a cross-fade involves opacity not position so why would something being cross-faded reach "a certain distance from the top of the page"?

Comment: And how does the text of the question relate to the title. A lot of imagination is required to make them tally - much more than I possess.

Comment: Tried removing `class=cf3FadeIn` from `#cf3` `html` , selecting `jQuery` and `onDomready` at jsfiddle ? See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6c8w76bx/43/

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Sorry about the wording. Yes my cross-fade already works, but it is activated when page finishes loading. I want it to activate when it reaches a certain distance from the top of the page (i.e when user scrolls and it is in the viewers vision)

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks, I saw your edit, but there's 2 problems. First, when the page loads, default image should be the black one (not the white), then when user scrolls down, the animation from black to white begins. Second, if you scroll slowly you can see the white image under the black, and then it suddenly disappears when the animation is activated. I've been trying to fix it but with fail...

Comment: @RoryH Try http://jsfiddle.net/6c8w76bx/59/embedded/result/ , moved `img` having class `top` to top , `img` with class `bottom` beneath

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry it's still not correct. This is what it should look like http://jsfiddle.net/6c8w76bx/62/ but you see the animation is loading instantly after page load. I want to make this animation only activate when you scroll down. If you dont scroll down it stays on the first frame (black frame).

Comment: @guest271314 tbh amended the code corectly in the post below, check http://jsfiddle.net/6c8w76bx/64/  Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @guest271314 I saw your post below just now. Yes that worked too! Thanks. Both solutions came at the same time, interesting to see both methods. I noticed you deleted the post though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the scroll removed: http://jsbin.com/hehide/edit

add a class 'active' or whatever you want to...

```
.cf3FadeIn img.top.active {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

and add/change your selector to:

```
  $('.top').addClass("active");
```

this is just one way to handle it, the real problem is that your elements need to have the animation added when the event happens (by adding the class that has the animation on it), not before, and this is assuming that your scroll logic works.

Comment: Tried your method but still couldn't get it to work.. But yes, I need the animation to be added only after you scroll down. Without scrolling down, the image should remain black. Easier said than done though! http://jsfiddle.net/6c8w76bx/62/ is exactly what it should look like but the image should remain black until scrolling down. The scroll logic works because I've used it with static images.

Comment: Genius. That works beautifully! So much hassle for something that looks so simple.. I appreciate the time you took on this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try

css

```
#cf3 img.top {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* set `paused` `animation-play-state` value */
  -webkit-animation-play-state : paused; 
}
```

js

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#cf3').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+100) {
            // substitute `$("img.top", this)` selector : `img.top`
            // for `$(this)` selector : `div#cf3` DOM element 
            // set "running" `animation-play-state` value
            $("img.top", this).addClass("cf3FadeIn")[0]
            .style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6c8w76bx/63/embedded/result/

See also , [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) , [animation-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)